# mvc button avoid page refresh without using ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Good day,

I have a button

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="/servicios/ChangeFieldToFalse?Id=4">change field to false</a>
```

and this in my backend

```
 public ActionResult ChangeFieldToFalse(Guid Id)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var result= _myclass.changeFieldToFalse(servicioId, userId);
       return .....
    }
```

Is it possible to avoid refreshing the page without using ajax? if so, how would I do it? I mean, I click on the button, a field in a table is changed to false.

Thank you .

Comment: If you want to update the existing page with data based on the server, then you must use ajax (and why do you want to refresh the whole page?)

Comment: thank you , I wrote I want to avoid refreshing it

Comment: You do not need to refresh the whole page - just update what you want (but you cannot do that without using ajax)

Comment: It is impossible to update only certain part(s) of the main view without using AJAX callback. Using standard GET method with anchor link without AJAX will refresh entire view page.